# Align div element at the bottom of another div element using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-5, vertical-alignment

I have three cards which can be displayed side by side.

Motivations is, that the orange part with the icon should be always displayed at the bottom, when all are displayed side by side. How can I achieve this?

I expected to achieve this with `align-items-end`, but it didn't work.

Currently, there may be many of redundant classes used.

The ideal solution would use only Bootstrap classes.

Detailed code below and [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laughingskull/fx5uvsgj/11/):

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
.coolspan {
  background-color: #a71a0b !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center">Title</h2>
<div class="row justify-content-center d-flex">
  <div class="m-3 py-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 justify-content-center border rounded-2 border-dark flex-column position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center coolspan rounded-2 shadow align-items-end">
      <i class="bi bi-person-circle big-icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m-3 py-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 justify-content-center border rounded-2 border-dark flex-column position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex ">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center coolspan rounded-2 shadow align-items-end">
      <i class="bi bi-person-circle big-icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m-3 py-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 justify-content-center border rounded-2 border-dark flex-column position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex ">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center coolspan rounded-2 shadow align-items-end">
      <i class="bi bi-person-circle big-icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I believe you can remove the `d-flex` class because the Bootstrap `row` class came up with the default `display: flex` CSS property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your markup a bit, and this uses only Bootstrap classes. Here's what I changed:

1. Remove `col-md-6`, `flex-column` and `justify-content-center` from your main wrapping column. Those are unnecessary. `col-sm-6` will work until you get to your `lg` rule and we don't need this element to display `flex-column` or `justify..` since it isn't a flex element - those classes don't do anything.
2. Wrap `img`, `p` and icon `div` in a `div` that **is** a flex parent. We give it a height of 100% `h-100`, this is so we can put the icon at the bottom.
3. Unwrap the `img` tag, you really don't need that parent container.
4. Set the icon div classes to `w-100` - width 100% and `align-self-end` which will position it to the bottom of the new wrapping div. This works because the wrapper is set to flex direction row, because `d-flex` by default is direction row - and `align-self` positions the cross-axis - in this case the y or vertical.

**EDIT**
Minor update (doesn't change the solution) - remove the `d-flex` class from your `row` element. Bootstrap `row` classes are already have the `display: flex` property set

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
.coolspan {
  background-color: #a71a0b !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-center">Title</h2>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="m-3 py-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 border rounded-2 border-dark position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap h-100">

      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg">

      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      <div class="w-100 align-self-end d-flex justify-content-center coolspan rounded-2 shadow align-items-end">
        <i class="bi bi-person-circle big-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-3 py-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 border rounded-2 border-dark position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap h-100">

      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg">

      <p>
       "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      <div class="w-100 align-self-end d-flex justify-content-center coolspan rounded-2 shadow align-items-end">
        <i class="bi bi-person-circle big-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-3 py-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 border rounded-2 border-dark position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap h-100">

      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg">

      <p>
       "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      <div class="w-100 align-self-end d-flex justify-content-center coolspan rounded-2 shadow align-items-end">
        <i class="bi bi-person-circle big-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```